# /boot/upgrade not found on Ubuntu 16.10 with Berryboot

Tags: kernel, apt, ubuntu, berryboot, dpkg

**Hi!**

I am using Berryboot on my Raspberry PI 3 to boot between Raspbian, OPENElec, RetroPie & Ubuntu Server 16.10, Everything works smoothly except for one thing;

When using the Apt-get command to install, remove or purge a package I get a response back telling /boot/upgrade is missing after the package is being installed/removed.

Ofcourse i did check if the /boot/upgrade dir exists and it does.

For example:

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mc
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1,077 kB disk space will be freed.
(Reading database ... 101084 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing mc (3:4.8.17-1) ...


ERROR BEGINGS HERE:

Setting up linux-firmware-raspi2 (1.20161020-0ubuntu1~1.1) ...
Error: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
dpkg: error processing package linux-firmware-raspi2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Setting up u-boot-rpi:armhf (2016.03+dfsg1-6ubuntu2~1.2) ...
Error: missing /boot/firmware, did you forget to mount it?
dpkg: error processing package u-boot-rpi:armhf (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-firmware-raspi2
 u-boot-rpi:armhf
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong? I searched the internet for this problem but I cant find anyone who has the same problem.

Thank you in advance!
- Bram.

Comment: @Milliways did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: did you ever get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed both packages and it still works fine, even upgraded the Ubuntu version. Think these packages are not required because as I understand it kernel and booting it taking care of by berryboot. That's probably causing conflicts/confusion in this configuration step.